# Scala: get param default value: can't access `apply$default$i` inside companion object

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-macros

I'm writing a macro that needs to get the default value of a constructor parameter. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21970758/1314705) shows this can be done by accessing the compiler-generated method `apply$default$i` on the companion object, where `apply` is the constructor's name and `i` is the 1-based parameter index.

However, this doesn't work if the macro is called from inside the companion object itself. Presumably the typechecking of the code in the companion object happens before the compiler generates the `apply$default$i` method.

This code works (whether written manually or generated by the macro):

```
case class C(i: Int = 1)
object C 
def x: Int = C.apply$default$1
```

But this doesn't:

```
case class C(i: Int = 1)
object C {
  def x: Int = C.apply$default$1
}
```

scalac complains that `value apply$default$1 is not a member of object C`.

I need to call the macro from the companion object because the macro defines an implicit typeclass instance.

I could generate code that will, at runtime, use reflection to access the `apply$default$i` method. But this is inelegant. If I know the compiler is going to generate a certain method, how can I access it in compiled code?

Comment: Seems this problem went away as of Scala 2.11.8 - now accessing default params from inside macro call in companion object works.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the relevant comment.](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/NamesDefaults.scala#L24)

```
  // Default getters of constructors are added to the companion object in the
  // typeCompleter of the constructor (methodSig).
```

Maybe your macro could substitute your own namer [in the attachment](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.5/src/compiler/scala/tools/nsc/typechecker/Namers.scala#L956) to enter your additional methods at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious workaround is to generate the method calling `apply$default$1` outside the companion object *and* a method calling this method inside:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

case class C(i: Int = 1)
object C { def y: Int = x }
def x: Int = C.apply$default$1

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

defined class C
defined module C
x: Int

scala> C.y
res6: Int = 1
```

Comment: As I said in the question: I need the macro to be called from the companion object because it creates an implicit typeclass instance. And a macro can't generate code that will be placed elsewhere from where it was called.

Comment: " I need the macro to be called from the companion object because it creates an implicit typeclass instance." I still don't see the problem: `y` returns whatever `x` does, which may be a typeclass instance (but it would be a problem if it needs to access private members of the class), and `y` can be implicit. "And a macro can't generate code that will be placed elsewhere from where it was called." Yes, so you either need to only implement `x` with a macro, or use a macro annotation with a sufficiently wide scope.

Comment: The whole point of using the macro is that users don't have to also manually write methods that (in this case) expose their default arguments. And I don't want to use annotation macros because they require the paradise plugin and I'm writing a library.